# How to check if the array inside object has elements of interest?

Tags: javascript

Hi i have an object like so,

```js
const obj = {
    id: '1',
    itemData: [
        "type1",
        "type2",
        "type3",
    ],
}
```

sometimes this itemData array can be empty array.

now i have to check if itemData has "type1" or "type2". if so then should return true if not false.

i have tried like below,

```js
const isDisabled = obj.itemData.map(e => return e === "type1" || e==="type2")
```

but this doesnt work. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: thats not valid syntax for an arrow function, remove the `return` --- also see [`<Array>.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `includes` with `some`

```js
const obj = {
    id: '1',
    itemData: [
        "type1",
        "type2",
        "type3",
    ],
}

console.log(!obj.itemData.length || obj.itemData.some(el => ['type1', 'type2'].includes(el)));
```

> The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array
> passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns true
> if, in the array, it finds an element for which the provided function
> returns true; otherwise it returns false. It doesn't modify the array.

[MDN - some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain
> value among its entries

[MDN - includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: thanks. how can i also set it to true if itemData is empty array?

Comment: @stackuser I changed the code.